# How to find force needed to lift two wheels off ground during cornering?

Tags: forces, kinematics, torque, rotational-kinematics

I'm attempting to calculate the maximum velocity at which I can safely drive around a corner.

One scenario I'm considering is where all four wheels maintain contact with the ground, but slips. The force needed to do this is simply the normal force multiplied by the coefficient of static friction.

However, the other scenario is where the two inner wheels lift off the ground, which can cause a rollover. However, I'm not sure how to derive a formula.

I have drawn a free-body force diagram, where the friction force points left, centripetal force points right, weight points down, and normal force points up. However, I do not know how to resolve the components of a force that can cause rotation around the right wheels, as I have not dealt with rotation in a free-body force diagram. Any help will be appreciated.